# Python 3.11 asyncio vs threadpoolexecutor when performing huge amount of I/O bounded tasks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I have a giant file with 3+ million lines of code and the size of a file is around 4GB. But size should not be a limiting factor, i.e it can grow (even 10GB).

I have investigating two possible solutions for processing that giant file line by line concurrently. By processing I mean that each line is being parsed and put into database transaction, which will be committed at the very end of giant file parsing.

The first approach is to use `asyncio.TaskGroup`:

```
import asyncio

async def parse_line(line):
    # process here
    # store to db txn
    print(line)


async def read_file_async():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as group:
        with open("super_large_file.txt") as file:
            for line in file:
                group.create_task(parse_line(line))

asyncio.run(read_file_async())
```

But what I got on output is:

```
Process finished with exit code 137 (interrupted by signal 9:SIGKILL)
```

Second approach is using `ThreadPoolExecutor`:

```
from concurrent import futures

def parse_line(line):
    # process here
    # store to db txn
    print(line)


def read_file_async():
    with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=500_000) as pool:
        with open("super_large_file.txt") as file:
            for line in file:
                pool.submit(parse_line, line)

read_file_async()
```

And the second approach works fine. Taking about 45 seconds. Which is acceptable. But my main concern is that why it is crashes under `asyncio.TaskGroup` as far as I know coroutines are much cheaper in creation/maintenance than system threads that are spawn by `futures.ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Comment: The number of tasks / threads you are creating is far beyond a reasonable value. The process might get killed because it exhausted the system resources.

Comment: How is `parse_line` updating the database? Does it have a way of doing the updates asynchronously? If not, you will get no performance improvement. If so, how is the database accessed? For example, can all of the tasks share a single connection if a connection is involved? How many connections can be created? Also, `read_file_async` is not reading in the file asynchronously and so no lines will be processed until all lines have been read in. Use `aiofiles` from the PyPi repository. I would certainly change `parse_line` to take a batch (i.e. a `list`) of lines to create fewer tasks.

Comment: Which part is it that you are treating as 'io bound'? because, your file reading is not done async anyway (though it should be, with aiofiles).  You need to rearchitect your solution and, yes, aim for a much smaller number of workers.  Remember, if you have .5 million workers each running an insert somehow, that's .5 million separate db connections.  huge huge waste (thus batching).  Can you do an architecture where a group of workers pulls in batches of lines and puts them in a work queue from which another work group pops them and inserts them?  Experiment with group sizes. probably <= 10